# California financial document verbiage: 3 months instead of 90 days?

Tags: california

Is there a law in California about the verbiage used in financial transaction language regarding the need to use the language "3 months" instead of "90 days"?

I was told that this is the case, but I cannot find can't reference to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Need to use* is too strong a claim but 90 days is a different period of time than 3 months.

90 days from 1 July is 29 September but 3 months is 1 October.